# Envio de ficheros FTP con phyton

Tags: python, ftp

Estoy enviando un fichero por FTP usando Phyton.

Mi código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
import os
filename = "MyFile"
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xx.xx.xx")
ftp.login("UID", "PSW")
ftp.cwd("/Unix/Folder/where/I/want/to/put/file")
os.chdir(r"\\windows\folder\which\has\file")
myfile = open(filename, 'r')
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + filename, myfile)
myfile.close()
```

El problema lo tengo en el uso de `ftp.storlines()` o `ftp.storbinary()`. En el caso que el fichero sea de tipo binario o sea de texto.

¿ Como determino que comando debo usar ? ¿ Se puede enviar siempre como binario independientemente de lo que sea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En FTP la idea de la transferencia en Ascii es la de poder compatibilizar los saltos de línea entre sistemas, por ej. en Windows: `\r\n` en Unix `\n`. Esto es por que en modo Ascii se transfieren líneas, y el SO que recibe estas las salva con el salto de línea correspondiente. ¿Que elegir? y dependerá de lo que busques, si quieres subir una archivo de texto desde un Windows a un Unix (o visceversa) y que el mismo pueda ser leído correctamente luego en un editor de texto usaría el modo `storlines()`, si lo que se busca es transferir cualquier archivo sin ninguna modificación del contenido `storbinary()`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Usaré siempre `storbinary()`. Los enviós se realizan simpre entre sistemas operativos Windows.